# Smack 4.2 and CCS (XMPP to FCM/GCM) - response incorrectly parsed by Smack - drops JSON payload

Tags: android, json, xmpp, smack

Version 4.2 of the Smack library seems to drop the message body, as sent by FCM.
When I set the debugger on, I can see the following incoming message:

```
<message><data:gcm xmlns:data="google:mobile:data">{"message_type":"nack","from":"xxx","message_id":"aaaa1","error":"BAD_REGISTRATION","error_description":""}</data:gcm></message>
```

However, when Smack 4.2 parses this message, it drops the JSON body inside the message and gives me the following in my packet listener:

```
<message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data"></gcm></message>
```

Here's my test class:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.*;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class CcsClient {

    private static final String HOST = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
    private static final int PORT = 5235;
    private final XMPPConnection conn;

    public CcsClient(String senderId, String serverKey) {
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

        ConnectionConfiguration conf = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
        conf.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        conf.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
        conf.setServiceName(HOST);
        conf.setSendPresence(false);
        conf.setCompressionEnabled(false);
        conf.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        conf.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        this.conn = new XMPPConnection(conf);

        conn.addConnectionListener(new AbstractConnectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void connectionClosed() {
                super.connectionClosed();
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                super.connectionClosedOnError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                super.reconnectingIn(seconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                super.reconnectionFailed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                super.reconnectionSuccessful();
            }
        });

        try {
            conn.connect();
            conn.login(senderId + "@gcm.googleapis.com", serverKey);
            System.out.println("connected!");
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {

        private final String json;

        public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
            super("gcm", "google:mobile:data");
            this.json = json;
        }

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            return "<gcm xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\">" + StringUtils.escapeForXML(json) + "</gcm>";
        }

        public Message toPacket() {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.addExtension(this);
            return message;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final CcsClient c = new CcsClient("xxx", "xxx");
        c.conn.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                System.out.println("incoming!" + packet.toString());
            }
        }, new PacketFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
                return true;
            }
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            c.conn.sendPacket(new GcmPacketExtension("{\"to\":\"xxx\", \"message_id\":\"aaaa"+i+"\", \"delivery_receipt_requested\":true}").toPacket());
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it working. An example client is here: https://gist.github.com/judepereira/fd8dc0a5321179b699f5c5e54812770c